# To run a full node, should I get a static IP address from my ISP?

Tags: network, nodes, p2p

I have a router connecting my home LAN to the ISP. After opening port 8333 on the router, and forwarding it the computer running the node, bitnodes.io confirmed the node was reachable. However, bitnodes.io sees the IP address the ISP is currently assigning to my router on the trunk (Internet) side, which may change over time.

Do I need to ask my ISP for a static IP address, to be assigned to my router, trunk-side?

Comment: You don't need static IP as Michael Folkson mentioned in the answer below. You can also try running Bitcoin Core as Onion service: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md Your screenshot reveals information about your browser, OS, bookmarks, add-ons, browsing habits, country etc. I would avoid sharing such screenshots except if it is test environment.

Comment: You can get a dynamic dns service that will maintain a single IP even though your ISP is constantly changing it.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an dynamicDNS services allow a static hostname, not a static IP. To have a static IP with the ISP changing it, you would have to proxy through a server with a constant IP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run a Bitcoin full node you don't **need** to have a static IP address as when your IP address changes you should still be able to find peers and connect to them. However, if you want to maintain the same peers getting a static IP address is a good idea. Your connection to existing peers will drop if your IP address changes and you will either reconnect to them with your new IP address or connect to different peers. This isn't generally a problem because you are only receiving information on transactions and blocks from other nodes rather than in Lightning's case having funds locked up with them.

If you are planning to run a Lightning node it is much more important that you have a static IP address as you will have funds in a channel with another peer that identifies you using that IP address. Changing the IP address for your Lightning node poses greater challenges at this point.